# how to extend/modify the dictionary in Stanford NLP?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

i've got special words and compound nouns
that should be identified as nouns in my system.

eg.:

i.) "XYZBrand" a brand name that's not in the standard dictionary

ii.) "copper wire" should be treated as 1 token all throughout the system.

both ""XYZBrand" and "copper wire" above should be treated as a noun each. 
or, rather, 
it's all fine if they are treated the way any other noun, say 
"jacket" is.

as far as i could see, StanfordNLP is doing just so for the first case above. 
when it sees a token that's not in the dictionary, it's 
taking it as a noun(?).
so, this is all about the compound nouns-- like "copper wire" above.

from what i see, there's the following ways of doing it:

1.) add the compound words to the dictionary from the start: 
so that StanfordNLP will tokenize them so and process on from the beginning. 
how to do this? this is the way i'm looking to go.

2.) define a `GrammaticalRelation` in `UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations` to 
see these compound words. this would work. however i wont always need `parser` in the pipeline and this doesn't "feel" like a proper twist.

3.) tokenize them so-- whenever there's "copper" and "wire" side by side, take the two as one token. 
however, this takes tempering with `edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer` 
and i'm not much willing to do so.

4.) write an annotator to go in right after `TokenizerAnnotator`.

5.) pre-process the text before feeding into Stanford-NLP: turn "copper wire"
into "copper-wire" for instance. this is the solution i least like.

how to add new terms to the dictionary in the system?

TIA.

//===========================

EDIT:

"copper" and "wire" when appearing side by side separated by whitespace(s) 
is **always** meaningful as one token-- "copper wire" in our context.

looking up the type dependency to see whether it's a 
compound noun with the "right" 
kind of other token(s) isn't a favorable choice:

- our "compound nouns" aren't always groups of nouns. "small contanier" 
  should also be one token in our system.
- will take looking up the token, say "copper" and checking 
  its dependency relations 
  with other tokens and will slow it down. 
  this is looking up our set of words and 
  tracing the dependencies-- "amod" for "container" and "compound" for "wire"
  just about in every step.
- i'll look to turn around other things. Eg.: in

  ```
  "some sugar and a bit of salt"
  ```

"sugar" and "bit" are "conj:and"-ed accurately by the grammer. 
however, "conj:and"-ing "sugar" and "salt" is more accurate in our context.

once i find a fine way to inject in my own dictionary to override 
the dictionary the tokenizer and tagger are using, or rather, to override 
the trained behaviour of the tokenizer and tagger, i can bend the system 
to process on our own set of terms. this Q is to look for that way to do this bend.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's some confusion about the underlying technologies running in Stanford CoreNLP. I'll try to clear up some confusion, and then suggest an approach at the bottom of the post.

- Our tokenizer is indeed a deterministic lexer. It would be possible to change it to treat "copper wire" as a single token, but this is actually I believe not the expected behavior: both "copper" and "wire" are distinct tokens and together form a compound noun.
- Our part-of-speech tagging system is not based on a dictionary at all. Rather, it's a probabilistic sequence model, trained on a corpus of training examples. We can add additional training data, but not additional dictionary items. Furthermore, the tagger *does* correctly get both "copper" and "wire" as nouns.
- A `GrammaticalRelation` defines a type of dependency edge -- for example, `compound`. This is, I believe, already the edge that you want, and there shouldn't be a need to define additional relations.

In terms of a solution, you can easily find compound nouns by running the dependency parser (the `depparse` is very fast) and then looking for groups of nouns connected with the `compound` arc. Once you have found these compound nouns, you can do one of two things.

1. Less recommended: re-tokenize the sentence such that these nouns are treated as single tokens; or
2. Recommended: treat the head word of the compound noun span (i.e., the word out of which the `compound` edges are coming) as your token, and then when you have to recover the full noun simply add in all the `compound` edges. So, in your case, treat "wire" as the placeholder for "copper wire," and simply recover the "copper" part on-demand when needed from the dependency tree.

Comment: you seem to have gone ahead of us in figuring what we want. i'll try to clear them up in an edit.